# String not being passed as query in retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit

I am having problem sending string parameters as query using @Field("test")
It works with Integer

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/yokitab/forum.php")
Call<List<QuestionData>> getQuestions(
        @Field("id") int id,
);
```

works

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/yokitab/forum.php")
Call<List<QuestionData>> getQuestions(
        @Field("question") String ques
);
```

doesn't work

Comment: if you want to send it through query you have to use the annotation Query

Comment: how have you defined your `getQuestions()` method?

Comment: Casting String to int may help you. `Integer.parseInt("ques");`

Comment: Have you tested, that such request surely works in outern program like Postman?

Comment: @R.Zagórski - Will try it.

Comment: It was fixed. Actually when you pass a String to retrofit API method, you must specify the .toString() even if what you're passing is a string !